# How to write a "for" loop to merge the production companies in one single row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, which shows movies and their corresponding revenue and production company. As you can see in the picture, some movies are the result of the collaboration of multiple production companies, hence the same title is shown as many times as how many production companies produced that movie (e.g. "Avatar", "Star wars", "Titanic"):

[image]

Here is the dictionary of the dataframe:

```
{'id': {0: 299534,
  1: 19995,
  2: 19995,
  3: 19995,
  4: 19995,
  5: 140607,
  6: 140607,
  7: 140607,
  8: 299536,
  9: 597,
  10: 597,
  11: 597,
  12: 135397,
  13: 135397,
  14: 135397,
  15: 135397,
  16: 135397,
  17: 135397,
  18: 420818,
  19: 420818,
  20: 24428,
  21: 24428,
  22: 168259,
  23: 168259,
  24: 168259,
  25: 168259,
  26: 168259,
  27: 168259,
  28: 168259,
  29: 168259,
  30: 168259,
  31: 168259,
  32: 99861,
  33: 284054,
  34: 284054,
  35: 12445,
  36: 12445,
  37: 181808,
  38: 181808,
  39: 181808,
  40: 330457,
  41: 330457,
  42: 351286,
  43: 351286,
  44: 351286,
  45: 351286,
  46: 109445,
  47: 109445,
  48: 321612,
  49: 321612,
  50: 260513,
  51: 260513},
 'comp_name': {0: 'Marvel Studios',
  1: 'Dune Entertainment',
  2: 'Lightstorm Entertainment',
  3: '20th Century Fox',
  4: 'Ingenious Media',
  5: 'Truenorth Productions',
  6: 'Lucasfilm',
  7: 'Bad Robot',
  8: 'Marvel Studios',
  9: 'Paramount',
  10: 'Lightstorm Entertainment',
  11: '20th Century Fox',
  12: 'Fuji Television Network',
  13: 'Amblin Entertainment',
  14: 'Legendary Entertainment',
  15: 'Universal Pictures',
  16: 'Dentsu',
  17: 'The Kennedy/Marshall Company',
  18: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  19: 'Fairview Entertainment',
  20: 'Marvel Studios',
  21: 'Paramount',
  22: 'Abu Dhabi Film Commission',
  23: 'Universal Pictures',
  24: 'China Film Co.',
  25: 'Original Film',
  26: 'Fuji Television Network',
  27: 'Québec Production Services Tax Credit',
  28: 'Colorado Office of Film, Television & Media',
  29: 'Dentsu',
  30: 'Media Rights Capital',
  31: 'One Race',
  32: 'Marvel Studios',
  33: 'Marvel Studios',
  34: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  35: 'Warner Bros. Pictures',
  36: 'Heyday Films',
  37: 'Lucasfilm',
  38: 'Ram Bergman Productions',
  39: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  40: 'Walt Disney Animation Studios',
  41: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  42: 'Amblin Entertainment',
  43: 'Legendary Entertainment',
  44: 'Universal Pictures',
  45: 'Perfect World Pictures',
  46: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  47: 'Walt Disney Animation Studios',
  48: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  49: 'Mandeville Films',
  50: 'Walt Disney Pictures',
  51: 'Pixar'},
 'revenue': {0: 2797.800564,
  1: 2787.965087,
  2: 2787.965087,
  3: 2787.965087,
  4: 2787.965087,
  5: 2068.223624,
  6: 2068.223624,
  7: 2068.223624,
  8: 2046.239637,
  9: 1845.034188,
  10: 1845.034188,
  11: 1845.034188,
  12: 1671.713208,
  13: 1671.713208,
  14: 1671.713208,
  15: 1671.713208,
  16: 1671.713208,
  17: 1671.713208,
  18: 1656.943394,
  19: 1656.943394,
  20: 1519.55791,
  21: 1519.55791,
  22: 1515.047671,
  23: 1515.047671,
  24: 1515.047671,
  25: 1515.047671,
  26: 1515.047671,
  27: 1515.047671,
  28: 1515.047671,
  29: 1515.047671,
  30: 1515.047671,
  31: 1515.047671,
  32: 1405.403694,
  33: 1346.739107,
  34: 1346.739107,
  35: 1341.511219,
  36: 1341.511219,
  37: 1332.539889,
  38: 1332.539889,
  39: 1332.539889,
  40: 1330.764959,
  41: 1330.764959,
  42: 1303.459585,
  43: 1303.459585,
  44: 1303.459585,
  45: 1303.459585,
  46: 1274.219009,
  47: 1274.219009,
  48: 1263.521126,
  49: 1263.521126,
  50: 1241.891456,
  51: 1241.891456},
 'title': {0: 'Avengers: Endgame',
  1: 'Avatar',
  2: 'Avatar',
  3: 'Avatar',
  4: 'Avatar',
  5: 'Star Wars: The Force Awakens',
  6: 'Star Wars: The Force Awakens',
  7: 'Star Wars: The Force Awakens',
  8: 'Avengers: Infinity War',
  9: 'Titanic',
  10: 'Titanic',
  11: 'Titanic',
  12: 'Jurassic World',
  13: 'Jurassic World',
  14: 'Jurassic World',
  15: 'Jurassic World',
  16: 'Jurassic World',
  17: 'Jurassic World',
  18: 'The Lion King',
  19: 'The Lion King',
  20: 'The Avengers',
  21: 'The Avengers',
  22: 'Furious 7',
  23: 'Furious 7',
  24: 'Furious 7',
  25: 'Furious 7',
  26: 'Furious 7',
  27: 'Furious 7',
  28: 'Furious 7',
  29: 'Furious 7',
  30: 'Furious 7',
  31: 'Furious 7',
  32: 'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
  33: 'Black Panther',
  34: 'Black Panther',
  35: 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2',
  36: 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2',
  37: 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi',
  38: 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi',
  39: 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi',
  40: 'Frozen II',
  41: 'Frozen II',
  42: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
  43: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
  44: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
  45: 'Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom',
  46: 'Frozen',
  47: 'Frozen',
  48: 'Beauty and the Beast',
  49: 'Beauty and the Beast',
  50: 'Incredibles 2',
  51: 'Incredibles 2'}}
```

I want to reach the goal of obtaining a dataframe where the movies appear ONLY ONCE, and the corresponding production companies are all in one row.

I thought of developing a "for" loop that basically says "If a movie under the column *title* repeats, then the companies under the column *comp_name* have to be "merged" in one single row (this kind of command is valid for "revenue" and "id" column too of course, since their values repeat too of course).

I know the following "for" loop is false, but just to give you a better idea:

for title in title:
if df.title.duplicated==True
*comp_names merged in one cell*

(I know this for loop is completely messed up, but I'm still learning. thanks)

Comment: something like `df.groupby(['id', 'title', 'revenue'])['comp_name'].apply(list)` should work

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks a lot. Yout line works to a certain extent: it does group the three columns, but the new "comp_name" column shows only one of the production companies unfortunately (all the others get excluded from the dataframe). I am trying to find a solution to this

Comment: Ok! Sorry, I'm kind of new here

Comment: That's okay! I'm sorry for being curt. Welcome

Comment: Thanks to you for the patience and the kindness! And thanks to you I learned how to insert the dictionary of my dataframe

Comment: I tried running the `df.groupby(['id', 'title', 'revenue'])['comp_name'].apply(list)` on your actual code, and I don't get the same thing as you - I have multiple companies in each row. Could they be cut off in your program or something?

Comment: See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BklhB.png

Comment: Sorry, I was running your code to frame that output in a dataframe. I was making the mistake of putting a "df" under your code, which of course wasn't containing the effects of your code (because your code is written without the variable "df=". Picture follows

Comment: This was my mistake:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhUig.png

Comment: ohhhh I see now. Fair fair! I have made this mistake before. I literally did it today haha

Comment: when i see `for loop` and `dataframe` in the same sentance, i know there is an error.

Comment: @D.L I, on the other hand, have a Minority Report-like ability to know errors have been committed before they happen